# My new Windows 7 Professional 64 bit does not recognize my external monitor

Tags: windows-7, external-display

I have a Lenovo w530 laptop running Windows 7 Professional 64bit which cannot see my Viewsonic VG2030wm monitor, no matter what driver is installed. I contacted Viewsonic support who sent me links to drivers for Windows 7 Vista and XP-64, neither of which resolved the issue. Does anyone have a driver that will allow my new laptop to see my external monitor?
Thanks!

Comment: is this a VGA cable going from the laptop to the monitor, what is your monitor saying, looking for connection and then going into power saver mode? When you right click an empty space on the desktop and select screen resolution, when you highlight the external monitor and then from the dropdown menu select "Extend desktop to this display" what happens? Can you adjust your monitor to look for analog VGA, maybe it is in DVI mode?

Comment: Thanks so much! And yes, this is a VGA cable going from the monitor to the laptop. When plugged in an powered on the monitor comes up only with a blue box that states "No signal detected. Analog". When I right click and empty space on the desktop and select screen resolution, there is only one monitor and when I choose 'detect' it still sees only one monitor, and the message "Another display not detected." is displayed. Any other suggestions? Please? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Sherrille, check out this PDF link I found and go to page 37. Looks like you need to do 2 things. #1. Switch to Discrete Graphics in the BIOS #2. Once you are in Windows press the Fn key + F7 to toggle between the different "external monitor/projector" modes. Here are the links I found, read number 2 on this first link - http://blog.pearce.org.nz/2012/08/enabling-external-monitor-on-lenovo.html and then go to page 37 of this PDF on this link http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/t530_w530_ug_en.pdf

Comment: page 23 of that same PDF describes how the Fn key works on your keyboard "Switching a display output location" - Seems like that is the same as right-clicking the desktop, selecting Screen Resolution, and adding a display.

Comment: Thank you so much! This cleared up the problem. My large, external monitor is now visible by the laptop and can now be used.

Comment: Awesome, now if you could thumbs up my Answer that would be sweet ;)

Answer (score 1):

check out this PDF link I found and go to page 37. Looks like you need to do 2 things. #1. Switch to Discrete Graphics in the BIOS #2. Once you are in Windows press the Fn key + F7 to toggle between the different "external monitor/projector" modes. Here are the links I found, read number 2 on this first link - http://blog.pearce.org.nz/2012/08/enabling-external-monitor-on-lenovo.html and then go to page 37 of this PDF on this link http://www.lenovo.com/shop/americas/content/user_guides/t530_w530_ug_en.pdf